# repopulate form data from an existing document

Tags: forms, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to repopulate fields on a HTML form with a users data they initially filled out when they created an account for the first time in Meteor to allow them to edit information. The form contains various inputs, option lists and check boxes. The data stores on in the collection with no issues. I have a field in the user profile called profComp which is either true of false dependent on if the form has been filled out before. I have tried to add an if/else statement on the route  -

```
Router.route("/edit_dashboard", function(){
  if(Meteor.user().profile.profComp)
  {
    this.render("change_edit_dashboard");
  }
  else
  {
    this.render('edit_dashboard');
  }
```

The change_edit_dashboard is a copy of the html form the user initially filled out and I have added a helper to the change_edit_dashboard template to retrieve the users info document from the collection.

```
  Template.change_edit_dashboard.helpers({
    formData: function()
    {
      return Base.findOne({_id: Session.get('baseId')})
    }
  });
```

And attempted to call context of document using spacebars {{#with}} in change_edit_dashboard

```
<template name="change_edit_dashboard">
  {{#with formData}}
    ----> form code <------
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

However a few strange things seem to be happening -

- The change_edit_dahsboard template is not rendering at all. The formData helper doesn't seem to be getting called as I am not getting a test console.log() I wrote showing in the console.
- With the addition of this code it seems to breaking all functionality of other templates. I have placed test console.log() in various template events and they do not seem to be getting called

Can anyone advise on where I may be going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you did not give us your form code, I'll just assume you correctly gave `<input name="myInput" value=myValueHelper>` attributes to your inputs and go on.
From what I see, you are trying to get data from one of the most error-prone objects in Meteor, `Meteor.users` when one wants to retrieve data from a collection object. You can find below some possibilities regarding your issue:

- `Meteor.user().profile.profComp` does not exist. As you are manipulating `Meteor.users` collection, you have to take a few extra-step in order to access data stored there. For example, if I have a `mySuperField` field at the root of my `Meteor.users` model, I have to publish it server-side in order to subscribe and retrieve it on the client. You can quickly check it by calling `Meteor.user()` and see wether it's present or not.
- If you have a blank screen with no error server-side, it's often because you broke your templating load. Check error messages at the top of your web-console and make sure you did not put a template helper in a file executed on the server or before your .html file was loaded by Meteor.

I'm not exactly sure why you need 2 edit templates but if it's just a matter of new vs edit, you should consider using autoform with simple-schema as it will greatly help you through your forms. You can find the links below.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform